# SAS STUDIO - How do I MOVE an imported .csv file (now a .sas7bdat file)

Tags: csv, sas

(SAS Studio / SAS Enterprise Miner On Demand  -- web access for school.)

I uploaded and imported a .csv file with SAS Studio.  The import function will only let me select the libraries WEBWORK and WORK (temporary), which are not viewable from SAS EM.  The import created WEBWORK.INPUT and "/home/my_username/.sasstudio/webwork/RS2999/import.sas7bdat.

How do I move that "../import.sas7bdat" file to "/home/my_username/my_content/(etc)" so I can see it from SAS EM?

(I can upload .sas7bdat files directly where I need them with SAS Studio, and that's where I uploaded the .csv file.)

Thanks

Comment: Well it seems to be unanimous across the internet.  Nobody knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Base SAS library in Studio and SAS EM pointing to the same location. Since this is in your home directory a metadata library would be overkill. I recommend using the Libraries tab in Studio and creating a library to "/home/my_username/my_content/(etc)" and then in EM open the Explorer ( View - Explorer) and create a library to the same location. They do not have to have the same name, but it would be a best practice to do so.